# uploading multiple xfiles to firebase storage

Tags: flutter, file-upload, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload multiple (max 5) xfiles images (image_picker library) to firebase storage. currently, it uploads only one with the below method:

```
Future<void> addProduct({
BuildContext? ctx,
String? proName,
String? productDescription,
double? count,
double? price,
required List<XFile> images
}) async {
try {
  var imageUrls = await Future.wait(images.map((_image) =>
    uploadFile(_image)));

  await firestore
      .collection(outletsCollection)
      .doc(_currentUserOutletId)
      .set({
    products: FieldValue.arrayUnion([
      {
        productId: Uuid().v4(),
        productName: proName,
        prodDesc: productDescription,
        countInStock: count,
        productPrice: price,
        productImg: FieldValue.arrayUnion([imageUrls]),
      }
    ]),
  });
} catch (err) {
  String errMsg = "error blahblah";
  errorDialog(ctx!, errMsg);
}
notifyListeners();
}
```

for the uploadFile method i tried using images.forEach() instead of .map(), but it gave me void type error. uploadFile method:

```
Future<String> uploadFile(XFile _image) async {

var storageReference = storage
    .ref()
    .child('product_images')
    .child(_currentUserOutletId!)
    .child(Uuid().v4());

final metadata = SettableMetadata(
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  customMetadata: {'picked-file-path': _image.path},
);

if (kIsWeb) {
  await storageReference.putData(await _image.readAsBytes(), metadata);
} else {
  await storageReference.putFile(io.File(_image.path), metadata);
}
return await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
```

}

so, at the end only one image is uploaded and addProduct() does not add product to firestore database. log in android studio returns nothing. I couldn't find a method that would work with the xfile. help appreciated very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<XFile> _imageFileList;

try{
final pickedFile = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
setState(() {
            _imageFileList = pickedFile;
     _imageFileList.forEach((element) async {
    firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;
                var date = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
                try {
                  setState(() {
                    _loading = true;
                  });
                  firebase_storage.UploadTask task = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('uploads/photos/'+date.toString()+'_image.png').putData(await element.readAsBytes(), SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'));

                  await storage.ref('uploads/file-to-upload.png').putData(await element.readAsBytes(), SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'));
                  firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot  downloadUrl = (await task);

                  String url = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());
                  // print(url.toString());
                } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
                  // e.g, e.code == 'canceled'
                  setState(() {
                    _loading = false;
                  });
                }
    });
```

try this way using image_picker plugin. You can get url after image upload and you have yo it in your data.